# Is it possible to prevent Meteor/IronRouter from reloading/rerendering when changing Routes?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, famo.us

I have a long list and detail page build with meteor-famous-views. If I switch from the list on the details page and go back again, the list is re-rendered. Is there a way to prevent this?

Is it possible to prevent Meteor/IronRouter from reloading/rerendering when changing Routes?

Unfortunately, the app does not run in Meteorpad. So please check my example app on github. 
https://github.com/handplant/meteor-famous-views-router-test

What is the best pattern to do this with iron router?

Excuse my insufficient English skills, please. :)

Thx

Comment: Hi Andee, welcome to SO! Please post some actual code in your question so it is still valid even if GitHub someday gets offline. :)